# Save the state of radiobutton

Tags: android, sharedpreferences

I am having 5 radiobuttons in my application and i want to save their states so that when i exit and then come back to the application then i see the same button clicked which was clicked prior to my exiting the application

Following is my code for saving the state

```
private int flag1 = true;
private void save(final boolean isChecked) {

    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("check", isChecked);
    editor.commit();
}

private boolean load() { 
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    return sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check", true);
}

protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    save(!flag1);
    SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
}

 @Override
 protected void onResume() {

    super.onResume();
    save(load());
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),""+load(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

I am calling the save method from inside the onCheckedChangeListener for every radiobutton but nothing happens.
```

Is there any other method of using sharedpreferences ??

Comment: Are you always saving "check"?!

Comment: everytime the application is paused "check" is saved as is visible in the code onPause() method sir

Comment: So, as I suspected, you write the same value for all the radiobuttons! if you write that checked is true or false, you'll never know WHICH is true or false...

Comment: ok sir i got what you are trying to say

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you are saving all button state using same key(check). Try something like this

```
private void save(int radioid,final boolean isChecked) {

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putBoolean("check"+radioid, isChecked);
editor.commit();
}
```

In load method loop through all radiobutton

```
private void load() { 
SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
for(int i=0;i<radioGroup.getChildCount();i++){
   RadioButton rbtn=(RadioButton)radioGroup.getChildAt(i);
   rbtn.setChecked(sharedPreferences.getBoolean("check"+rbtn.getId(), false)); 
 }
}
```

**UPDATE**

In RadioGroup only one button is checked at a time.
so store check button id instead.

```
private void save(int radioid) {

SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();
editor.putInt("check", radioid);
editor.commit();
}
```

and use following code to restore

```
private void load() { 
   SharedPreferences sharedPreferences = getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

   int radioId=sharedPreferences.getInt("check", 0);
   if(radioId>0){
     RadioButton rbtn=(RadioButton)radioGroup.findViewById(radioId);
     rbtn.setChecked(true); 
   }

 }
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use this code

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("setting", MODE_PRIVATE);

    if(sp.getInt("checked", 0) != 0){

    rg.check(sp.getInt("checked", 0));

    }
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
    RadioGroup rg = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioGroup1);
    int id = rg.getCheckedRadioButtonId();
    SharedPreferences sp = getSharedPreferences("setting", MODE_PRIVATE);
    Editor e = sp.edit();
    e.putInt("checked", id);
    e.commit();
    }

}
```

and here is layout:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<RadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="53dp" >

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio0"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:checked="true"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />

    <RadioButton
        android:id="@+id/radio2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="RadioButton" />
</RadioGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also try override:

```
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("radioButton1", true);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("radioButton2", false);
    savedInstanceState.putBoolean("radioButtonN", false);
}

public void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    boolean rb1_state = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("radioButton1");
    boolean rb2_state = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("radioButton2");
    boolean rbN_state = savedInstanceState.getBoolean("radioButtonN");
}
```

methode

Answer (score 0):

use `SharedPreferences` in a separate helper class. That way you could initialize the `SharedPreferences` in the start of the activity and check if there were any values present there.

You can see the code example [here](https://github.com/rakeeb11/simple-shared-preferences/blob/master/src/com/example/storagesharedpref/prefs/SharedPref.java). Doing this ... as I said in the `onCreate` you could check if the `SharedPreferences` has any value. Check the full source code [here](https://github.com/rakeeb11/simple-shared-preferences).

Answer (score 0):

save your radio button value using shared preferences like this

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LEVEL", 0);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = settings.edit();
    editor.putBoolean("FIRST", radiobutton1.isChecked()); // first argument is a                                                        

    editor.commit(); // Commit the changes
```

And to load this you have to set it to default true/false.

```
    SharedPreferences settings = getSharedPreferences("LEVEL", 0);
    boolean isChk= settings.getBoolean("FIRST", false);
```

and to use this write down below code

```
    if (isChk)
     radiobutton1.setChecked(true);
```